# Labeling data in BarChart

Tags: charts

I have the following data:

```
data = {{1.2, 1.1, 1.4, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.2, 1.1, 1}, {1.3, 1.4, 1.2, 
1, 1.1, 0.8, 1.1, 1.2, 1}};
```

and I would like to make a `BarChart` where each bar has a label with the corresponding value. Basically, I would like to add Labels to the bars in:

```
BarChart[Thread@data, ChartLabels -> {Placed[Range[1, 9], Below], None},
Frame -> True,FrameTicks -> {False, True},
BaseStyle -> {Large, FontFamily -> "Arial", Black},
BarSpacing -> {0, 0.8},PlotRange -> {All, {-0.3, 2}}, 
PlotRangePadding -> {0.8, {0, 0}},AspectRatio -> 0.4,ImageSize -> 800,
FrameStyle->Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[3]]]
```

How to manage this?

Also, I would like to add a legend for the two colors.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation of [`BarChart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarChart.html)? [`ChartLabels`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChartLabels.html) should be useful for you. For the second part, [`ChartLegends`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChartLegends.html) should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap each data point with `Labeled` and add the option `ChartLegends -> {"Group A", "Group B"}`

```
BarChart[Labeled[#, Style[#, 14], Center] & /@ # & /@ Thread @ data, 
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[Range[1, 9], Below], None}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {False, True}, 
 BaseStyle -> {Large, FontFamily -> "Arial", Black}, 
 BarSpacing -> {0, 0.8}, PlotRange -> {All, {-0.3, 2}}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {0.8, {0, 0}}, AspectRatio -> 0.4, 
 ImageSize -> 800, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[3]],
 ChartLegends -> {"Group A", "Group B"}]
```

[image]

Or, keep `Thread @ data` as the first argument and add the option

```
LabelingFunction -> (Placed[Style[#, 14], Center] &)
```

to get the same picture.